# Copy multiple arrays from an open workbook to specific sheets (for each individual array) in a closed workbook without overwriting any information

Tags: excel, vba

I have 5 different arrays of data to export to a single closed workbook but each array has to paste to a different sheet into the next open row.  I don't want any data to be overwritten just added too.  This is what I have so far for one array.  I know its not even close but any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub Export_Data_To_File()
Dim Y As Integer
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Dim i As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
FileToOpen = Application.Workbook.Open("S:\Process Engineering\Team Documents\010 Alpha\Alpha Laser 
Calibration\Raw Data\Raycus Laser Decay Comparison.xlsx")
If FileToOpen <> False Then

    Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("G6:L6").Copy
     Y = 2
     i = 0
       Do While i = 0
        If Cells(Y, 2) = "" Then
            OpenBook.Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("Y,2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            i = 1
        Else
            Y = Y + 1
       End If
     Loop
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
      
    Workbooks("Raycus Laser Decay Comparison.xlsm").Save
    OpenBook.Close False


End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("Y,2")` ----> probably should be `Cells(Y, 2)`.

Comment: probably useful... [Find the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba).

Comment: Application.Workbook**s**.Open